# What differences would there be inside a world where the sun/moon are in orbit around the Earth?

Tags: space, earth-like, orbital-mechanics

Suppose some crazy-ass god or whatever decides to create its beautiful project: the planet Earth. And of course it is the central key of its universe. The sun, the moon, nearby planets, all of they are in orbit around the earth, not the other way around (id est: all around the sun). Farther stars may or may not be orbiting around the earth.

My question is: what main changes would there be in this earth-centered universe (specifically to this earth population)? Would there be changes in the seasons, the number of days a "year" has? Would the days be shorter/longer? Would the tides be f*****-up completely? Dusk/dawn would be different? What about eclipses?
In short, what things that in our earth prove that the sun does not orbit around our planet would actually happen in this imaginary world?

Please consider I'm not interested anything that occurs outside this imaginary planet. Just what differences would there be inside this world and our world.

It is assumed that the idea is to have the sun and the moon working similarly to our own (the sun heats the earth to sustain life, moon should affect the tides and stuff...), but I'm more interested in what would actually happen, and how it would affect its inhabitants.

Magic may or may not be involved.

Comment: we can't encompass the whole universe in a single answer. Please considerably narrow your question down

Comment: I don't want the whole universe, only what would happen to that earth. The rest of the universe/galaxy is out of the question.

Comment: You are asking for a (endless, potentially) list of what would happen to Earth. Again, too broad.

Comment: Fair point. I guess it's just too big, my bad.
Thanks for everything :)

Comment: Just narrow it down to one aspect/problem and it might be fine

Comment: This site uses the model one-specific-question/one-best-answer. At the time of my comment, your question includes the effect on ants, my little sister, and the dirt on top of my car's tail pipe. It's still way too broad. Just asking about climate changes might be too broad (that's a very complex subject). The magic reference means there's no useful answer because you can do anything you want (e.g., the star is sized down to have the same effect on the earth, so now you have an earth with two moons and one is shiny. That's basic research.) Specific, please.

Comment: Finally, keep in mind that if the sun were sized to be in orbit with Earth (like being a second moon), you'd have 13th century astronomy where they actually did think the sun orbited the Earth. Without taking in very specific gravity effects, there's no practical difference, which is why early astronomy had so much trouble seeing the difference.

Comment: Ok, I might just drop the question whatsoever ;) It is indeed too much. I'll try to think it long enough before re-asking it. You might close it completely if you want it ;)